# Groovy , what does -> mean

Tags: groovy

In examples of groovy code I find the `->` operator everywhere, but the groovy tutorials nor the book I have seem to provide any explaination as to what this means.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is used to separate where you declare bindings for your closure from the actual code, eg:

```
def myClosure = { x, y -> x + y }
```

the part before `->` declares that the closure has two arguments named `x` and `y` while the second part is the code of the closure.

You can omit it in closures with just one parameter, in that case the `it` variable is assumed:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each{ println it*2 }
```

but you could also do

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each{ lol -> println lol*2 }
```

Comment: Scala and C# use => for the same purpose, while -> originally meant (*a).b in a->b, so it's easy to get confused by Groovy's strange choice.

Answer (score 12):

[image: figure demonstrate the use of ->]