# Does this Groovy closure token '->' have a name or a nickname?

Tags: groovy, closures

Followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993462/groovy-what-does-mean). [Groovy.codehaus.org](http://Groovy.codehaus.org) just refers to it as a token. Are there any informal monikers floating around like 'splat' and 'bang'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is informally known as "the arrow". I cite [this post from 2008](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/When-do-I-need-the-arrow-td356227.html). Though I can't claim it is a standard idiom, I've never heard it called anything else (in conversation).

Answer (score 1):

In the [antlr parser script](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/antlr/groovy.g#L1708), it's called the 'closable block operator'

I don't know of a snappier name than 'arrow'

Answer (score 0):

I've heard it called "Rocket" before.
Also a "Fat Rocket"/"Hash Rocket" would be '=>'

But this more applies to Ruby lingo.